# New laptop stated to have up to 3.6 GHz, i5. System Information states only 1 Ghz i5 - why?

Tags: cpu

I just ordered a new laptop from direct from Dell, on the Dell website and on the invoice the CPU is stated as a :

> 10th Generation Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1035G1 Processor (6MB Cache, up to 3.6 GHz)

The laptop has arrived and im setting it up, under the system information dialog in W10 it reports the following :

> Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1035G1 CPU @ 1.00GHz, 1190 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)

Am I understanding this correctly ? Is this saying that i ordered a laptop with a CPU of upto 3.6Ghz (which i presumed would be a standard clock speed of c. 3 GHz) but they have shipped me a laptop with only a 1Ghz CPU ?

Although the Dell website didnt state the actual clockspeed of the CPU i presumed it would be c. 10-20% lower than the stated boost speed, as it has been on manly laptops and desktops ive owned in the past.

Does this mean that my new laptop will be slow ?

Am i focusing on the wrong metric here (eg. clockspeed) should i run a Geekbench test instead to get a better understanding, of this machine at its CPU.

Answer (score 0):

**"Up to"** is the key point to note.

It has a base frequency of 1.0GHz & a maximum frequency of 3.6GHz, which it will ramp up to… as & when needed.

From [Intel Ark](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/196603/intel-core-i5-1035g1-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-60-ghz.html)

[image]

Comment: Why do they put the base speed so low, is it for power consumption ? If i have the laptop plugged into the power, can it run for consistant long periods at higher speeds ?

Comment: It runs at higher speeds when it needs to. If you want it to run a Word document at full speed, with your fans going like helicopters, you can bypass it… but why would you want to?

Comment: I was reading up on Turbo boost on intel's website and they state "Intel® Turbo Boost Technology 2.01 accelerates processor and graphics performance for peak loads, automatically allowing processor cores to run faster than the rated operating frequency if they’re operating below power, current, and temperature specification limits" where i have such a low clocked CPU, does this mean to extract performance out of the CPU it will be in turbo boost allot of the time ?

Answer (score 0):

To add to Tetsujin's answer, if you disable StepSpeed in BIOS (if such option is available), the CPU should always run at max freq. It's a power saving feature.

Comment: Maybe he IS a helicopter pilot...